# Ionic Modal Appear on load

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Morning all,

I've started a new project based on the [Ionic Side Menu starter app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu). How do I get the login form modal to appear on load rather than on menu click?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
$scope.modal.show();
```

Somewhere in your controller, after the `$scope.modal` value has been defined.

Comment: So does that mean you can write statements outside of function implementations? E.g. in the template, controllers.js contains $scope.doLogin, so I could just write the statement before that?

Comment: Yes. The function declarations are actually just declaring variables, that happen to be functions.